# ggplot connects lines vertically according to x-axis variable rather than grouping variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

I want to plot a line graph with multiple lines. I have three conditions and I want to plot a line with three points for each condition. For some reason, ggplot is joining the lines vertically, so instead of three horizontal lines connecting the three points within a group, I have three vertical lines connecting all the points between a group for a single point on the x-axis. I can't work out what I've done wrong.

This is my code:

```
#this is a list of 9 numbers to be plotted in 3 lines on the y axis
means <- c(574.7685, 580.7797, 574.9977, 575.3367, 584.8480, 574.8543, 574.7309, 585.2841, 574.1599)

#defining the groups that I want to plot separate lines for
group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)

#The x axis categories
Measurement_Time <- c("0-Pre-adaptation","5-post","60-post")
 
#put the above in a dataframe
mean_red <- data.frame(Measurement_Time, group, means)

#plot
ggplot(mean_red, aes(x = Measurement_Time, y = means, colour = group)) + geom_line()
```

And the output is:

[This problem plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HXku.png)

When what I want is:

[This sensible plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D8d7.png)

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to SO.

When simply using visual aesthetic mappings is not enough to differentiate the groups, then you need to also provide a `groups` aesthetic. See: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html.

Also, you should set `groups` in your dataframe to be a factor so that ggplot interprets it as discrete items, rather than a continuous variable.

In my code below, I've generated data because your example code has variables that you didn't provide (min15, hour1, hour4). Please include them next time!

```r
    library(ggplot2)
    
    set.seed(12345)
    
    #this is a list of 9 numbers to be plotted in 3 lines on the y axis
    means <- sample(1:10, 9, replace = TRUE)
    
    #defining the groups that I want to plot separate lines for
    group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
    group <- as.factor(group)
    
    #The x axis categories
    Measurement_Time <- c("0-Pre-adaptation","5-post","60-post")
    
    #put the above in a dataframe
    mean_red <- data.frame(Measurement_Time, group, means)
    
    #plot
    ggplot(mean_red, aes(x = Measurement_Time, y = means, colour = group, group = group)) + 
        geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: How do you interpret the error `geom_line(): Each group consists of only one observation.` when we remove `group = group`? As far as I know, the `color` aesthetic also groups the data but apparently in a different way than `group` in this case.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for this help, this works for me! I've also edited my post to include the data - apologies for not including it in my original post.

Comment: @dufei See the link I provided in my answer. Short answer: `groups` aesthetic is usually guessed based on the visual aesthetics you asked for, but sometimes it is not enough. This happens most often for geom_bar(), geom_histogram(), and geom_line(). The full warning (not error) that you should have gotten (esp. if you are running up-to-date ggplot2) was: `geom_line(): Each group consists of only one observation. ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?`, so it's giving you a clue to what you need to do.

Comment: @ErinWarden-English nice, remember to Accept the answer that was most useful so that this question can be marked as resolved 

Comment: It does, I'm just wondering how `geom_line()` would get this wrong since the variable `group` clearly has three levels with 3 obs each. Apparently, there is some interaction with the variable that is mapped to the x-axis going on. If that is numeric, there is no issue.

Comment: @dufei Like you observed in your answer, it interacts with OP's choice of a categorical variable on the X axis when it really should be a continuous variable. If you look at the dataframe that comes out of `mean_red`, it really **is** the case that `group = 1` occurs only once for `Measurement_Time = 0_Pre-adaptation`. Because Measurement_Time is categorical/discrete, ggplot doesn't want to join them together unless you specifically tell it to. But if X is continuous like in your answer, then it knows this is what you probably want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that what is mapped to color needs to be categorical, and what ends up on the x-axis should be numeric, like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mean_red <- tibble(
  means = rep(c(575, 580, 575), times = 3) + rnorm(9, sd = 5),
  group = factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)),
  Measurement_Time = rep(1:3, times = 3)
)

ggplot(mean_red, aes(x = Measurement_Time, y = means, colour = group)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This answer is the best one for future analyses; the main lesson here is to give ggplot the right sorts of variables so that it can make the right guesses. In particular for @ErinWarden-English, if you are taking measurements at irregular times, then using a continuous variable like minutes elapsed on the X axis will truthfully show those time differences. As it stands, it looks like the measurements were taken at regular steps, but your time names don’t agree.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky to see given that we don't know exactly how `means` is supposed to be sorted. But from how it looks you are missing the `group` variable in `aes()`.

```
ggplot(mean_red, aes(x = Measurement_Time, y = means, group = group, colour = group)) +
    geom_line()
```